# Rollback own edit?

Tags: support, edits, user-interface

Could we have the ability to rollback our own edits?

Why? I just edited my own question slightly too hastily, realised I had been stupid, went to click "Rollback", and realised the button wasn't there, so I had to manually undo the edit..

I don't think it would be confusing UI-wise, although I guess "Rollback" could be thought of as the "Why did someone touch my stuff! Undo!" button..?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that already actually: if you are editing your question, you can select another revision in the upper drop down. This way you can easily rollback to previous revisions.